How to refactor code that uses @NgModule for Angular 18?
I am trying to use a library for drawing on an image (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-drawing-zone) and in the steps, the developer uses NgModule for importing ImageDrawingModule.
However, I started working with Angular 18 recently and have no experience with prior versions.
In Angular 18 there is not even a app.module.ts file.
How do I use this library without NgModule or maybe using a different structure for the code?
Here is my component file.


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationComponent } from '../navigation/navigation.component';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Category } from 'app/interfaces/category';
import { OfferService } from 'services/offer-service';
import { DataService } from 'services/data-service';
import { ImageDrawingComponent } from 'ngx-image-drawing';

@Component({
  selector: 'create-offer',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, NavigationComponent, ImageDrawingComponent],
  templateUrl: './create-offer.component.html',
})
export class CreateOfferComponent implements OnInit {
  createOfferForm: FormGroup
  categories: Category[] = []
  selectedCategories: string[] = []
  errors: Error | undefined;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private dataService: DataService,
    private router: Router,
    private offerService: OfferService
  ) { this.createOfferForm = new FormGroup({}) }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createOfferForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      price: ['', Validators.required],
      categories: ['', Validators.required]
    })

    this.dataService.getCategories().subscribe(
      (data: Category[]) => {
        this.categories = data
      }
    )

  }

  findInvalidControls() {
    const invalid = [];
    const controls = this.createOfferForm.controls;
    for (const name in controls) {
      if (controls[name].invalid) {
        invalid.push(name);
      }
    }
    return invalid;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('create-offer form submit')
    console.log(this.findInvalidControls())
    if (this.createOfferForm.invalid) return

    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('title', this.createOfferForm.get('title')?.value)
    formData.append('description', this.createOfferForm.get('description')?.value)
    formData.append('price', this.createOfferForm.get('price')?.value)
    formData.append('categories', JSON.stringify(this.selectedCategories))
    formData.append('status', "PENDING")
    formData.append('timeCreated', (Date.now()).toString())

    this.offerService.createOffer(formData).subscribe({
      next: (value) => {
        if (value) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl("/offers")
        }
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      }
    })
  }

  onChange(value: string) {
    if (this.selectedCategories.includes(value)) {
      const index = this.selectedCategories.indexOf(value, 0);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.selectedCategories.splice(index, 1);
      }
    } else {
      this.selectedCategories.push(value)
    }
  }
}





<navigation class="navigation"></navigation>
<div class="container mx-auto py-2 mt-3">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="createOfferForm"
    class="max-w-fit mx-auto bg-white shadow-lg rounded px-4 py-4 flex flex-col">
    <div class="w-full flex flex-col md:flex-row">
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 p-8">
        <h2 class="mb-4 text-blue-500 font-semibold">Create Offer Form</h2>

        <div class="mb-4">
          <label for="title" class="block mb-2">Title:</label>
          <input type="text" id="title" formControlName="title" required
            class="block w-full px-4 py-2 rounded border border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500">
        </div>

        <div class="mb-4">
          <label for="description" class="block mb-2">Description:</label>
          <input type="text" id="description" formControlName="description" required
            class="block w-full px-4 py-2 rounded border border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500">
        </div>

        <div class="mb-4">
          <label for="price" class="block mb-2">Price:</label>
          <input type="text" id="price" formControlName="price" required
            class="block w-full px-4 py-2 rounded border border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 p-4">
        <div class="mb-4 flex flex-col justify-between ">
          <label class="mb-2">Categories:</label>
          <div class="ml-2">
            @for(category of categories; track category){
            <label class="block mb-2">
              <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(category.category)" [value]="category.category"
                formControlName="categories" required>
              <span>{{ category.category }}</span>
            </label>
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-8">
      <button type="submit"
        class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded hover:bg-blue-600 focus:outline-none focus:bg-blue-600">Submit</button>
    </div>

  </form>

  <image-drawing [src]="imageUrl" outputMimeType="'image/jpeg'" outputQuality="0.8" (save)="save($event)"
    (cancel)="cancel()">
  </image-drawing>
</div>




you can import directly into standalone components @Component({standalone: true, imports: [...]}). However, it would be helpful to see your files

Add the html code and use the auto fix function of you IDE and ignore the first part of the documentation.

@GetOffMyLawn I have posted the files. The error I get is TS-992012: Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules.

@strandom The package uses angular 8, Its no longer compatible for angular 13+, plz look for alternative packages! package.json

You should still be able to add ImageDrawingModule to the imports of your standalone component
